# Установить background color только между графами (GraphView)

Tags: java, android

Библиотека: graphview 
Версия: 4.2.1

Можно ли в graphview задать background только между определенными графами, не выполняя полной заливки?
Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня получается только такое, используя setDrawBackground:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> seriesUp = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[]{
        new DataPoint(0, 3),
        new DataPoint(1, 7),
        new DataPoint(2, 5),
        new DataPoint(3, 4),
        new DataPoint(4, 8)
});
graph.addSeries(seriesUp);
seriesUp.setDrawBackground(false);
seriesUp.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
seriesUp.setDrawBackground(true);


LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[]{
        new DataPoint(0, 2),
        new DataPoint(1, 6),
        new DataPoint(2, 4),
        new DataPoint(3, 3),
        new DataPoint(4, 7)
});
graph.addSeries(series);
graph.getViewport().setScalableY(true);
series.setThickness(5);
series.setColor(Color.RED);
series.setAnimated(true);
series.setDrawDataPoints(true);
series.setDataPointsRadius(10);
series.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
series.setDrawBackground(false);
```

Заранее спасибо.